# php can't recognize table from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

I created tables in phpMyAdmin - but when I try to connect php to the table it says:

`can't use college unknown database 'college'`

I was trying to move a zip file to the folder where the php file is (using xampp):

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME','college');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');


$link=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link){
die('couldnt connect:'.mysql_error());

}


$db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);

if(!$db_selected){
die('can use'.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error());
}

echo 'connect successful';
?>
```

Comment: Are you running mysql locally on your server? Also, is there a database called `college` that can be accessed by the `root` user with no password?

Comment: Why not run a query from php **`SHOW TABLES`** to see actually what tables you have in your **`DB`** If you have successful DB connection from php

Comment: I created it without password...

Comment: Do i write 'show tables' in phpMyAdmin ot the document php I created?

Comment: You are trying to connect to a database called "college", check if it exists using : **show databases;**

Answer (score 0):

### First:

Confirm that you are accessing phpMyAdmin on the correct host. In your code, it's clear that PHP is attempting to connect to MySQL on `localhost`. Is phpMyAdmin running on `localhost`? If not, then you've identified your error - ensure that you are connecting to the correct server - wherever you are running phpMyAdmin.

### Second:

If you're sure that you are running phpMyAdmin on the same host as you're trying to connect to with your php, then double-check that the correct database actually exists.

[image: phpMyAdmin SQL tab - show databases]

Connect to phpMyAdmin, and select the tab labeled 'SQL' at the top. In the query box, enter `SHOW DATABASES;`, then select the 'go' button underneath the query box.

On the results page, ensure that your 'college' database exists. If it's not listed in the results, then you will need to re-create the database.

Otherwise, it's likely a permissions issue with your user (root) accessing your 'college' database.

If you provide more detailed information, we may be able to provide more assistance.